# Add values in a on to many construct but it seems that it would add it with one to one

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I have to add types of devices to a manufacturer. The manufacturer name should be unique.

[image]

In the relationship i have one to many from the manufacturers to the type and in the opposite I have the relationship many to one from the types to the manufacturers.

Now I try to add with this example some values:

```
struct ManufacturerListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var manufacturers: FetchedResults<ManufacturerEntity>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(manufacturers, id: \.self) { manufacturer in
                    Section(manufacturer.wrapedName) {
                        ForEach(manufacturer.typesArray, id: \.self) { type in
                            Text(type.wrappedNname)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button("Add Examples") {
                let type1 = TypeEntity(context: viewContext)
                type1.name = "T2"
                type1.manufacturer = ManufacturerEntity(context: viewContext)
                type1.manufacturer?.name = "Tormek"
                
                let type4 = TypeEntity(context: viewContext)
                type4.name = "T8"
                type4.manufacturer = ManufacturerEntity(context: viewContext)
                type4.manufacturer?.name = "Tormek"
                
                let type5 = TypeEntity(context: viewContext)
                type5.name = "sh222"
                type5.manufacturer = ManufacturerEntity(context: viewContext)
                type5.manufacturer?.name = "Scheppach"
                
            do {
                let done = try viewContext.save()
            } catch let error {
                let errortext = error.localizedDescription
                print(errortext)
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that the manufacturer would added seperate and it be not used as unique.

Where is my mistake? I can't see it.

I got the error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133021 "(null)" UserInfo={NSExceptionOmitCallstacks=true, conflictList=(
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x600000012d80) for constraint (\n    name\n): database: (null), conflictedObjects: (\n    \"0x6000015353c0 \",\n    \"0x6000015350e0 \"\n)"
)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
try? viewContext.save()
```

This throws an error, but you don't handle it, so you end up with erroneous results. Your code creates an erroneous situation but ignores the error by using `try?`.

When you have a uniqueness constraint like this and your code violates that constraint (as it does here), Core Data has conflicting requirements that need to be resolved somehow.

If you made it a `try` instead of a `try?` and you caught the error, you'd find that the error is an `NSConstraintConflict` that describes the conflict your code creates. You could have code in the `catch` block to resolve the conflict.

You could also choose a merge policy for your context, which would make it resolve the conflict automatically. There are several automatic options-- see the documentation for `NSMergePolicy` to chose one.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I will handle now the error and see what happen

Comment: do {
                    let done = try viewContext.save()
                } catch let error {
                    let errortext = error.localizedDescription
                    print(errortext)
                }

gives me the error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133021.)

Comment: Yes, Cocoa error 133021 is the `NSConstraintConflict`, I mentioned. If you cast the error to an `NSError` you can get details about it. It's probably easier to use a merge conflict.